# Dynamically Specify Linked Server and DB Names in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a query in a stored procedure that needs to be executed on different servers and databases according to some parameters.

How can I do this without using neither **exec**, nor **sp_executesql**?

I'm using **SQL Server 2008**.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I've found some links

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29397800/dynamically-specify-serve.aspx

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Is using **SYNONYM** possible solution? If yes, than how?

**UPDATE 2**

I forgot to mention that all this servers are linked to the server where stored procedure is stored.

**UPDATE 3**

**OPENROWSET** or **OPENDATASOURCE** are not accessible either. I need a solution without building query string concating server name, schema name, db name.

It surely can be done by using if or case in stored procedure, but if we have 37 variations, then it's not a good solution.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How many combination do you have of server & database, for which you want to execute the sql dynamically? example: db1.sp1, db1.sp2, db2.sp1, db2.sp2, db2.sp3?

Comment: 37, do you suggest using case or if?

Comment: SYNONYM wouldn't really help as you'd still need to change where the synonym points to which would require either dynamic SQL or a big hardcoded conditional statement. Could also cause problems with concurrency as the Synonym can only point to one thing at a time.

Comment: @Martin Smith, thank you for describing synonym:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody wants to answer, so I'll do it myself, just to have accepted answer.

There's isn't any way to do this. You need to use one of specified suggestions, anyway the query must be generating by concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

Does [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) or [`OPENDATASOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) help?

EDIT: If it works, you can change the database at runtime & execute the query using the present connection. I cannot see any other way of executing query the way you want.

What is wrong with running query using string i.e dynamic query?

Comment: These are linked servers, so I don't have problems with connecting to them. OPENROWSET or OPENDATASOURCE don't solve my problem, I just don't want to put my query in a string type.

Comment: @hgulyan But these take a string which you can easily build by concatenation.

Comment: @Martin Smith, I would do that with parameterized sp_executesql, if I have wanted to build my query string.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I have edited my questions. You see, the reason why I don't want exec or sp_executesql is that I don't want generating query string concating, as I said in update 3.

Comment: @hgulyan Well it isn't possible then without some massive set of if statements.

Comment: @Martin Smith, than write it as an answer and I'll accept it. I consider that I have to use sp_executesql.

Comment: @hgulyan - Leave the question open for a bit incase someone does have an idea of how this can be achieved. I definitely can't think of any way though!

Comment: @Martin Smith, I can't find any other solution either:(
p.s. anyway post your answer. I'll wait a while and accept your answer.

Comment: @hgulyan Does gbn's answer here help at all or is it not applicable to what you are doing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073544/set-database-name-dynamically-in-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: I didn't get how it works. Where should I add my query and what @p1, @p2?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* DO THIS FOR EACH TABLE IN THE PROCEDURE*/ 

--BEGIN TABLE_1  
DECLARE @LINKEDSERVER AS VARCHAR(50) 
 SET @LINKEDSERVER = DBO.FN_RETURN_SERVER('SBROUBLES')

DROP SYNONYM MYLINKEDSERVER
EXEC (' CREATE SYNONYM MYLINKEDSERVER FOR ' + @LINKEDSERVER + 'ANYDB.DBO.ANYTABLE')

--- END TABLE_1

-- UTILIZATION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYLINKEDSERVER


--AND FN_RETURN_SERVER COULD BE ANY SELECT CASE ON SQL AS WELL
```